# script optimization in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running simple select script, which inner join with other 3 table . all the tables are big ( lots of data ) its taking around 20 sec to run. want to optimized it.

I tried to used nolock , but not much deference

```
SELECT RR.ReportID,
       RR.RequestFormat,
       RRP.SequenceNumber,
       RRP.ParameterName,
       RRP.ParameterValue
       CASE WHEN RP.ParameterLabelOvrrd IS NULL THEN P.ParameterLabel ELSE .ParameterLabelOvrrd END AS ParameterLabelChosen,
       RRP.ParameterValueEntered
FROM ReportRequestParameters AS RRP WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN ReportRequests AS RR WITH (NOLOCK) ON RRP.RequestID = RR.RequestID
     INNER JOIN ReportParameter AS RP WITH (NOLOCK) ON RP.ReportID = RR.ReportID
                                                   AND RP.SequenceNumber = RRP.SequenceNumber
     INNER JOIN Parameter AS P WITH (NOLOCK) ON P.ParameterID = RP.ParameterID
WHERE RRP.RequestID = '2226765'
ORDER BY SequenceNumber;
```

Please advice.

Comment: The `with (nolock)` suggests SQL Server, so I added the tag.

Comment: What is your reason for choosing to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` against every table here? If it's to "improve" the performance then that *isn't* what `WITH (NOLOCK)` does and you should remove them all (your question suggests that's the reason). Your SQL is also malformed as you're missing a comma after `ParameterValue`, and `.ParameterLabelOvrrd` is missing the table alias. The quickest way for you to help us help you is for you to post the DDL of your tables, along with any indexes. It will likely be worth while giving us a copy of your [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) too.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT RR.ReportID, RR.RequestFormat, RRP.SequenceNumber, 
       RRP.ParameterName,  RRP.ParameterValue 
       COALESCE(RP.ParameterLabelOvrrd, P.ParameterLabel) as ParameterLabelChosen,
       RRP.ParameterValueEntered
FROM ReportRequestParameters RRP JOIN
     ReportRequests RR 
     ON  RRP.RequestID = RR.RequestID JOIN
     ReportParameter RP 
     ON RP.ReportID = RR.ReportID AND
        RP.SequenceNumber = RRP.SequenceNumber JOIN
     Parameter P 
     ON P.ParameterID = RP.ParameterID
WHERE RRP.RequestID = 2226765
ORDER BY RRP.SequenceNumber;
```

I have removed the single quotes on `2226765`, assuming that the id is a number.  Mixing types can impede the optimizer.

Then, I recommend an index on `ReportRequestParameters(RequestID, SequenceNumber)`.  I assume the other tables have indexes on the appropriate columns, but these are:

- `ReportRequests(RequestID, ReportID, SequenceNumber)`
- `ReportParameter(ReportID, SequenceNumber, ParameterID)`
- `Parameter(ParameterID)`

I strongly advise you not to use `nolock`, unless you know what you are doing.  Aaron Bertrand has a good [blog post](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) on this subject.

Comment: . . .  I would preferred `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE()`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . And I don't.  In this case, there is no performance difference and `COALESCE()` is a standard function.

Comment: . . . . In my experience i have faced performance difference so.

Comment: Depends on the datatypes of `RP.ParameterLabelOvrrd` &  `P.ParameterLabel` too, @YogeshSharma. The behaviour between the 2 is not the same, and `COALESCE` will produce the same behaviour that the OP currently has. `ISNULL` *may* not.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running with the execution plan turned on and see if SSMS can advise you on additional indexing.

Other than that your query looks straight-forward, nothing code  wise that is going to help make it faster, other than perhaps getting rid of the case statement and definitely getting rid of the NOLOCK statements.